# passing generic class with different type parameters between UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, user-controls, covariance

I currently have a couple different user controls that provide the same functionality:  three different buttons called Select All, Deselect All, and Toggle Selected.  These perform actions on a list of items that implement my `ICheckable` interface in each user control.  I wanted to unify this stuff so that the commands and buttons would all be defined in one place only--a new user control--instead of being duplicated in two different user controls.  My problem is that in one user control I'm dealing with a list of my `Template` class, and the other user control has a list of a `Defect` class.  Both `Template` and `Defect` implement `ICheckable`, meaning the Select All, Deselect All, and Toggle Selected apply to them.

I have a generic container class `SelectableItems<T>` that requires `T` fit these constraints:  `where T : ICheckable, IEquatable<T>, IDeepCloneable<T>`.  `SelectableItems<T>` provides an `ObservableCollection<T> Items` property, along with other useful properties such as `bool IsAnyItemSelected`, `T SelectedItem`, etc.  These properties would be used in implementing the Select All, etc. commands.  Both `Template` and `Defect` fit all those constraints.  I was going to create a dependency property in my new user control to which I would bind a `SelectableItems<Template>` and `SelectableItems<Defect>` property from my other user controls.  I don't think it's possible to do a generic dependency property, though, because I can't have a generic `UserControl` class since I'm using XAML.  How should I go about this?  I'm using .NET 3.5.

To sum up, this is what I want:

```
TemplateList user control                             ItemSelection user control
-------------------------------------------           --------------------------
SelectableItems<Template> TemplateContainer ==Bind==> unknownType? ItemContainer

DefectList user control                           ItemSelection user control
---------------------------------------           --------------------------
SelectableItems<Defect> DefectContainer ==Bind==> unknownType? ItemContainer
```

**Edit:** I considered just adding dependency properties to my new `ItemSelection` user control for all the useful properties in the `SelectableItems<T>` view model, such as `IsAnyItemSelected`, etc.  That would be fine for most of the properties, but I was hesitant to do it for `ObservableCollection<T> Items` because I hit the same generic problem as described above, and I didn't trust things to work okay if I just used `IEnumerable` instead of `ObservableCollection<something>`.  Maybe I should make an `ObservableCollection` class that isn't generic (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868793))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a non-generic `ObservableCollection` class and then using a value converter to convert my `ObservableCollection<T>` value to an `ObservableCollection` seems to have worked.

Here are the important parts of my `ObservableCollection` class:

```
public class ObservableCollection : ICollection<object>,
    INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<object> _collection;

    public ObservableCollection()
    {
        _collection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        _collection.CollectionChanged +=
            new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(collectionChanged);
    }

    public ObservableCollection(IEnumerable items)
    {
        if (null == items)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
        }
        _collection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        foreach (object item in items)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
        _collection.CollectionChanged +=
            new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(collectionChanged);
    }

    ...stuff necessary to implement ICollection<object>...

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    void collectionChanged(object sender,
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler = CollectionChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the value converter:

```
public class EnumerableToObservableCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(ObservableCollection))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Do not use this converter except " +
                "when going to ObservableCollection");
        }
        var enumerable = value as IEnumerable;
        if (null == enumerable)
        {
            return new ObservableCollection();
        }
        return new ObservableCollection(enumerable);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And I bind like so:

```
<local:ItemSelection SelectedItems="{Binding Path=MyViewModel.SelectedItems,
    Mode=OneWay}"
    Items="{Binding Path=MyViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay,
        Converter={StaticResource observCollConverter}}"
    IsAnyItemSelected="{Binding Path=MyViewModel.IsAnyItemSelected,
        Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: It just occurred to me I probably didn't need to write a non-generic `ObservableCollection`, I could've just used a converter to convert `ObservableCollection<Defect>` to `ObservableCollection<object>`...  Ah well.